# Admin Area in Drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I have a problem with Drupal: I build sites that have a protected area accessible only to site admins. I want to create a pseudo-admin role that has access to the protected area but I don't want them to access full admin/Drupal functionalities.

Which is the best thing to do in this case? Can I create a sub-admin area with styled access only to some areas (like creating content and others) without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Create a role, set the role permissions ( /admin/user/permissions ) to just what you need them to access.

If you need a styled theme for these users, check out sections module, you can do role and url specific themes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant permissions beyond content management, you may consider [Site Configuration Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/config_perms).

> The following permissions are added:
>
> - administer administration theme
> - administer clean-urls
> - administer date-time
> - administer error reporting
> - administer file system
> - administer modules
> - administer performance
> - administer site information
> - administer site maintenance
> - administer themes
> - display site building menu
> - display site configuration menu

Answer (score 0):

Like troynt said, the sections module is usually good for this type of thing.  It depends on your requirements, but when I once needed to set up a user section that was separate from the site and only shared certain data, so I set up a multisite with some shared tables

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 6 go under User Management / Roles and create a new Role (say subadmin) and grant him the rights
for Dupal 7 go under People / Permissions / Roles tab click where you add new Role and grant permissions.

Refer this Link :

http://planetghost.com/make_new_role